# Applying cart rules before tax in quote

Tags: magento

I am creating an order programatically in Magento and I have 3 price rules that are supposed to be applied for orders of a certain value (above 3000, above 4000, above 5000).

I have no problems creating the order, everything works fine however the price rule seems to be choosen based on the price before tax (all item prices in the shop are including tax).

I am setting the tax class on the items in the quote with

```
$product->setTaxClassId(2);
```

Which gives the following result

```
subtotal 4894
discount -147
shipping 0
tax 949
grand_total 4747
price_rule 7
```

price_rule 7 is the rule for above 3000 (should be above 4000). From what I can tell the problem comes due to the fact that the discount rule is chosen based on subtotal - tax where I would like it to be just subtotal.

Is there any parameter on the quote that I am missing that gives the behaviour I am after?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the admin panel then try to find out system>configuration>sales>tax
Then Calculation Settings-> Apply Discount on Prices . Then Change Including Tax to Excluding Tax. Hope this will solve your problem. Thanks.